# need assistance in google drive api oauth 2 without playground

Tags: php, curl, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I am using the Google API Playground to auth my PWA and get tokens to upload files to google drive from the PWA.

I'm using the Google Drive API, but the refresh token that I got from the Playground is expiring after one week. This causes us to go through the whole process from playground again.

I don't have this problem with other APIs, such as Dropbox, where the app refresh tokens aren't expiring and can be used to generate a new access token.

I am looking for help in:

1. Authorizing my PWA and get code in php using curl
2. Get a refresh token through my PWA without a consent screen

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description, but that doesn't tell us what _problem_ you're having. What have you tried, and what troubles did you encounter? Please [edit] your post to include a [valid question](/help/how-to-ask) that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is [on-topic](/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, opinions, and external links are off-topic.

Comment: Refresh tokens expire because your app is still in the testing phase.     Oauth2 playground is only meant for testing you need to have your code authorize itself.  rather then going though the playground.    You could use a service account if this is the only account you are connecting to then you wont need the consent screen.

Comment: thank you for the quic responses friends, 
yes it is in testing mode, 
i am generating tokens using my own id and secret,
so you say in production mode refresh_token will not expire, ok i shall check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets take this step by step

> I'm using the Google Drive API, but the refresh token that I got from the Playground is expiring after one week.

I am going to assume that you are using your own client id and client secret within Playground.

[image]

If this is the case then the reason it is expiring after a week is that your app is still in the testing phase.   To fix that you can go to google cloud console under the oauth2  consent screen and switch your app to prodctuion.

[image]

Request a new refresh token and it should not expire.

If you are not using your own client id then the reason its expiring is that developer console is not intended for production use its just for testing.   Stop using it in that manner.

> Get a refresh token through my PWA without a consent screen

If you only connecting to a single google drive account then you should consider using a service account.  A service account is intended for server to server authorization its pre authorized.   You can share a folder with a service account and the service account will have access to that folder without requesting a user grant consent.  It will just work.